# Using SMO in C# to backup SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, smo

I'm developing a simple utility which is going to create a `*.bak` file from a SQL Server database.

If database has a quite small size, less than 50 Mb, then there is no problem, it's working well. But potentially I'm going to work with big databases of 2-3Gb data size.

Since it's impossible (I guess) to keep such a big data in the memory to create `*.bak` file, would my utility still work in this case?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the code.

Comment: You have not constructed your question well.

Comment: How does the SQL Server Management Studio backup of such large databases work? The backup process is *streaming* the data to disk - chunk by chunk. It's not keeping the whole database in memory and then dumping it to disk....

Comment: insert junk into db, test yourself

Comment: Note: Default command timeout is set to 10 minutes, you can set property called `StatementTimeout` in the `ServerConnection` class. Setting this to zero disables the timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your utility will still work with databases that are 2 -3 Gb in size.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  behind the scene Sql Server Management Studio uses smo models for it`s tasks such as backup and restoring. it can handle backups so also you can do your job using smo functionality.